# Putting cp's suffix before extension

Tags: linux, cp

I was trying to get a one-line solution to copying a bunch of files inside a directory and its sub-directories into a single separate directory, and got the following:

```
find source/ -type f | xargs -I '{}' cp -a --backup=t '{}' destination/
```

It works well for the most part, only copying files and handling duplicate file names, but I'm wondering if there's a way to make it so the suffixes that come from the cp command go before the extension. Right now, if two files have the same name and are being copied into it, I'll get:

```
file.txt
file.txt~1~
```

If at all possible, I'd like to instead get `file~1~.txt` or even using a different delimiter like `file(1).txt` or `file-1.txt`.

It might get messy because it seems like the `cp` command wouldn't check before the extension to see if delimiters match, resulting in something like this: `file~1~~1~~1~.txt` eventually, but if anyone has any solutions that are easy, it'd be nice. Right now I'm dealing with it by piping `ls` into `vim` and doing a bulk-rename via global commands and writing to `!sh`.

Comment: What's the extension in `foo.tar.gz.split.1`?

Comment: I would probably see foo as the filename and everything after that as the extension, so the desired result would be `foo~1~.tar.gz.split.1`. There are probably edge cases like if a file's name contains periods, etc., but for a simple solution I'd like to just assume things are nice and simple.